# Should data classes that are passed between layers be abstracted?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I am working my way through "Dependency Injection Principles, Practices, and Patterns" to gain a better understanding of how to use DI.

The book provides an example using an ECommerce website. In this example, DI is used. The example maintains abstractions between the domain model, data access layer, and web UI, however, there is a line of code that appears (to me) to tightly couple the web UI layer to the domain model. This line of code exists in the HomeController class of the WebUI layer:

```cs
IEnumerable<DiscountedProduct> featuredProducts =
    this.productService.GetFeaturedProducts();
```

The `DiscountedProducts` class is a public class located in the domain model. I would have expected an abstract class or an interface to be used in its place to maintain loose coupling between the two layers. **Should the `DiscountedProducts` class be abstracted by using an abstract class or interface?**

The entire HomeController class is below:

```cs
namespace Ploeh.Samples.Commerce.Web.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IProductService productService;

        public HomeController(IProductService productService)
        {
            if (productService == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(productService));

            this.productService = productService;
        }

        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            IEnumerable<DiscountedProduct> featuredProducts =
                this.productService.GetFeaturedProducts();

            var vm = new FeaturedProductsViewModel(
                from product in featuredProducts
                select new ProductViewModel(product));

            return this.View(vm);
        }

        public ViewResult About()
        {
            return this.View();
        }
    }
}
```

And the entire `DiscountedProduct` class is below:

```cs
using System;

namespace Ploeh.Samples.Commerce.Domain
{
    // ---- Code Listing 3.6 ----
    public class DiscountedProduct
    {
        public DiscountedProduct(string name, decimal unitPrice)
        {
            if (name == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("name");

            this.Name = name;
            this.UnitPrice = unitPrice;
        }

        public string Name { get; }
        public decimal UnitPrice { get; }
    }
}
```

Additionally, the source code for this app is located [here](https://github.com/DependencyInjection-2nd-edition/codesamples/tree/master/RightECommerce/src).

Please let me know if I am mistaken and this code does maintain loose coupling between application layers.

Comment: `IProductService` - this interface is to allow loose coupling. `DiscountedProduct` is a POCO. Could you introduce an interface for it? Sure - but for POCOs the benefit generally isn't there. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/185636/should-i-create-interfaces-for-data-transfer-objects

Comment: Hi zwoolli, thank you for your post. It is unclear what your question is, or if there even is a question in your post. Can you please clarify? Your post is long, so **bolding your main question** will help others give you the answer you are looking for.

Comment: mjwillis, thank you for your answer and stackexchange link. POCOs are mentioned in the book, but it wasn't clear to me that POCOs do not need abstraction until your reply. So thanks!

Comment: Hi Connor - per your suggestion, I added a line to help clarify my question. Thanks for pointing out it lacked clarity 

Comment: You are welcome @zwoolii.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reading my book.

You are referring to the content of chapter 3 where the tightly coupled code base from chapter 2 is refactored to a loosely coupled code base.

As the start of section 3.1 (page 53) notes, in the tightly coupled code base:

> "*Volatile Dependencies were tightly coupled across the different layers.*"

The goal of the refactoring in chapter 3 (and about DI in general) is to prevent tight coupling on Volatile Dependencies. *Volatile Dependency* is a concept that was introduced and explained in section 1.3.2 (page 26).

The idea of the refactoring in chapter 3 is, therefore, to prevent the Domain Model from containing any Volatile Dependencies and from *preventing* it from taking a dependency on anything volatile.

In the context of DI, the Domain Model's `DiscountedProduct` data object is *not* a Volatile Dependency, which is explained in section 3.1.1 (page 58):

> "*From a DI point of view, POCOs, DTOs, and view models [...] aren't really interesting. They don't contain any behavior you might want to INTERCEPT, replace, or mock. They are mere data objects. This makes them safe to create in your code, so there's no risk in tightly coupling your code to these data objects. These objects contain the application's runtime data that flows through the system after classes like `HomeController` and `ProductService` have long been created.*"

In other words, `DiscountedProduct` is a *Stable Dependency* (section 1.3.1).

Dependency Injection is practiced to *increase* the maintainability of our software, but applying DI on *Stable Dependencies* has the opposite effect: When applied to *Stable Dependencies* the complexity of your software is *increased*, without reaping any additional benefits.

Comment: thanks for your answer and edits. Clearly I need to read a little more closely. However, your answer as definitely helped this information sink in.

Answer (score 1):

I think in this case you are mixing together two concepts:

- Dependency Injection
- Separation of Concerns

Dependency injection does not mean you should abstract everything out into interfaces or, well... abstract classes. Dependency injection is more about defining the relationships between classes/services and **extracting** that relationship out into a common interface.

What you've highlighted here is more about the architectural layering of the application. So we have the following components:

- `HomeController` depends on a...
- `IProductService` which produces...
- `DiscountedProduct`'s which is a data model used to communicate data between the controller and the service. Transforming this into an interface brings no real benefits. Then we have...
- The `View` which uses...
- `ProductViewModel` to display information to the end user

In the example given I'd say you have 3 different layers:

1. The service layer where `IProductService` lives
2. The controller (mapping) layer where `HomeController` lives
3. The presentation layer where data is rendered for the user

I call layer 2. a mapping layer because that's what the controller in this case does. Often the controller is (in my humble opinion) misused and contains too much business logic - but that's another discussion. When acting as a mapping layer the `DiscountedProduct` simply becomes, as stated above, a language that the controller understands and can translate into the "view model language" that the view understands. `DiscountedProduct` therefore has no reason to be an interface, because it acts as a strictly defined language used for the two layers to communicate.

This is for the same reason that the view model has no purpose being an interface as it exists to communicate data and not functionality.

Comment: Xerillio - thank you for laying out your thought process regarding the architectural layering and when abstraction makes sense. This answer is super helpful!